# I am not able to Razorpay payment getway intigretion in Flutter web, could you help me in this

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611186871348-b1ce696e52c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YXBwbGUlMjBsYXB0b3B8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80',
                  height: 250,
                  width: 350,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('macbook pro'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('description'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('rs200000'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('buy now'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Let's suppose this is the project then when we click on buynow button then razorpay popup should be open in website**

**Could you guys help me in this because I think razorpay doesn't provide any plugin for Flutter web **

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this package `razorpay_web: ^1.1.0` in `pubspec.yaml` file

Then copy the full code and paste in `main.dart` and run it works then enjoy..

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_web/razorpay_web.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611186871348-b1ce696e52c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YXBwbGUlMjBsYXB0b3B8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80',
                  height: 250,
                  width: 350,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('macbook pro'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('description'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text('rs200000'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Builder(
                  builder: (context) => Center(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text("Buy Now"),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Payments()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Payments extends StatefulWidget {
  const Payments({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PaymentsState createState() => _PaymentsState();
}

class _PaymentsState extends State<Payments> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RazorpayWeb(
          rzpKey: "rzp_test_DNaSxot4oJHykG", // Enter Your Razorpay Key Here
          options: RzpOptions(
            amount: 1000,
            name: "Razorpay",
            description: "Test Payment",
            image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png",
            prefill: const PrefillData(
              name: "Razorpay",
              email: "rzp@gmail.com",
              contact: "9876543210",
            ),
            colorhex: "#FF0000",
          ),
          onPaymentSuccess: (String paymentId) {
            print("Payment Success");
            log(paymentId);
          },
          onPaymentError: (String error) {
            print("Payment Error");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If payment is successful onPaymentSuccess Function will contain the payment_id from razorpay.

Comment: tried but did not work man ,could you help me what can i do

Comment: onPressed: () {
                      RazorpayWeb(
                        rzpKey:
                            'rzp_test_DNaSxot4oJHykG', // Enter Your Razorpay Key Here
                        options: RzpOptions(
                          amount: 1000,
                          name: "Razorpay",
                          description: "Test Payment",
                          image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png",
                          prefill: const PrefillData(
                            name: "Razorpay",
                            emai.....

Comment: Share your full code in question

Comment: That's the full code for now when we click buynow button shoul open razorpy in Flutter web

Comment: Where is Razorpay integration part of code?

Comment: I am not able post all that , have you tried brother at your level with this plugin to open razorpy in Flutter web ?

Comment: currently I didn't have the API key for testing

Comment: You can try this one brother = 
 rzp_test_DNaSxot4oJHykG

Comment: I hope i would positive response from you soon

Comment: @AbhiEntrepreneur any progress? Please consider accepting the answer if it helps you.

Comment: I already updated the answer. You didn't check the Answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71737427/18585332

Comment: wow amazing bro , you are time and life saver for me , kinda virtual guru

Comment: Hi Jackie brother , i need one more help of  you that how can we put dynamic data in razorpay option so razorpay can catchup data automatically automatically according to product ,, here is my repositry link =  https://github.com/AbhiEntrepreneur/razorpayweb        i hope i would get positive response from you

Comment: Ask a separate question bro...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71808921/17923759         here i asked bro, hope would get positive response bro

Comment: does razorpay_web: ^1.1.0 is official package from razorpay?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74587764/im-working-on-a-flutter-web-project-when-i-run-in-localhost-it-is-working-fine             brother could you resolve this issue