# i used razorpayWeb plugin in my flutter project but i am confused how to get dynamic data in razorpay options

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-razorpay

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:futurek/homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


***nav bar**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavBar({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer();
  }
}



*homepage*

import 'package:futurek/shoe_page.dart'; // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, unused_element

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:futurek/navbar.dart';

class CardItem {
  final String urlImage;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  const CardItem({
    required this.urlImage,
    required this.title,
    required this.subtitle,
  });
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  List<CardItem> items = [
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2529147/pexels-photo-2529147.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
      title: 'Nike Free Run',
      subtitle: '10',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://underarmour.scene7.com/is/image/Underarmour/3024250-404_DEFAULT?rp=standard-30pad|gridTileDesktop&scl=1&fmt=jpg&qlt=50&resMode=sharp2&cache=on,on&bgc=F0F0F0&wid=512&hei=640&size=472,600',
      title: 'Adidad free run',
      subtitle: '50',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpozlaZ5vCRX6qz1ISfI7a2swqpFXvivy47jR1POAai3qom_f4KIMOB-gQoXdnzeLOUXk&usqp=CAU',
      title: 'Reebok',
      subtitle: '70',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pair-pink-sport-shoes-on-260nw-228691018.jpg',
      title: 'Puma',
      subtitle: '89',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.creator-prod.zmags.com/image/upload/q_auto,dpr_2.625,f_auto/c_scale,w_300/621cf9017826497cf6ceb463.jpeg',
      title: 'Jordan',
      subtitle: '97',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 3),
            Container(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Category',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 0),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: false,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 5,
                separatorBuilder: (context, _) => SizedBox(
                  width: 12,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    buildCard(item: items[index], context: context),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // ignore: dead_code
  Widget buildCard({
    required CardItem item,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) =>
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    child: Material(
                      child: Ink.image(
                        image: NetworkImage(item.urlImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ShoePage(
                                        item: item,
                                      ))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 4,
              ),
              Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              Text(
                item.subtitle,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}


*shoepage*

import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:futurek/homepage.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_web/razorpay_web.dart';
import 'package:futurek/razorpaypopup.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class ShoePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CardItem item;

  const ShoePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShoePage> createState() => _ShoePageState();
}

class _ShoePageState extends State<ShoePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.item.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth < 768) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                  child: Image.network(
                    widget.item.urlImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Builder(
                    builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("BuyNow"),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Payments()),
                                ))))
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Row(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                  child: Image.network(
                    widget.item.urlImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Builder(
                    builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("Buy Now"),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Payments()),
                                ))))
              ],
            );
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}


*razorpaypopup*

import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:futurek/homepage.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_web/razorpay_web.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:futurek/shoe_page.dart'; // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, unused_element

class Payments extends StatefulWidget {
  const Payments({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PaymentsState createState() => _PaymentsState();
}

class _PaymentsState extends State<Payments> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RazorpayWeb(
          rzpKey: "rzp_test_DNaSxot4oJHykG", // Enter Your Razorpay Key Here
          options: RzpOptions(
            amount: 1000,
            name: '',
            description: "Test Payment",
            image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png",
            prefill: const PrefillData(
              name: "Razorpay",
              email: "rzp@gmail.com",
              contact: "9876543210",
            ),
            colorhex: "#FF0000",
          ),
          onPaymentSuccess: (String paymentId) {
            print("Payment Success");
            log(paymentId);
          },
          onPaymentError: (String error) {
            print("Payment Error");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hi guys, i used razorpayWeb plugin in my flutter project but i am confused how to get dynamic data in razorpay options so razorpay can catchup data automatically automatically according to product ,, here is my repositry link = github.com/AbhiEntrepreneur/razorpayweb i hope i would get positive response from you guys

Comment: repo link = github.com/AbhiEntrepreneur/razorpayweb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_web/razorpay_web.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(HomePage());
}

class NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer();
  }
}

class CardItem {
  final String urlImage;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  const CardItem({
    required this.urlImage,
    required this.title,
    required this.subtitle,
  });
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  List<CardItem> items = [
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2529147/pexels-photo-2529147.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
      title: 'Nike Free Run',
      subtitle: '10',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://underarmour.scene7.com/is/image/Underarmour/3024250-404_DEFAULT?rp=standard-30pad|gridTileDesktop&scl=1&fmt=jpg&qlt=50&resMode=sharp2&cache=on,on&bgc=F0F0F0&wid=512&hei=640&size=472,600',
      title: 'Adidad free run',
      subtitle: '50',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpozlaZ5vCRX6qz1ISfI7a2swqpFXvivy47jR1POAai3qom_f4KIMOB-gQoXdnzeLOUXk&usqp=CAU',
      title: 'Reebok',
      subtitle: '70',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pair-pink-sport-shoes-on-260nw-228691018.jpg',
      title: 'Puma',
      subtitle: '89',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.creator-prod.zmags.com/image/upload/q_auto,dpr_2.625,f_auto/c_scale,w_300/621cf9017826497cf6ceb463.jpeg',
      title: 'Jordan',
      subtitle: '97',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: NavBar(),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 3),
              Container(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    'Category',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 0),
              Container(
                height: 300,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  primary: false,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 5,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, _) => SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      buildCard(item: items[index], context: context),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // ignore: dead_code
  Widget buildCard({
    required CardItem item,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) =>
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    child: Material(
                      child: Ink.image(
                        image: NetworkImage(item.urlImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ShoePage(
                                        item: item,
                                      ))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 4,
              ),
              Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
              Text(
                item.subtitle,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class ShoePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CardItem item;

  const ShoePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShoePage> createState() => _ShoePageState();
}

class _ShoePageState extends State<ShoePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.item.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth < 768) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                  child: Image.network(
                    widget.item.urlImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Builder(
                    builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("BuyNow"),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Payments(
                                            title: widget.item.title,
                                            urlImage: widget.item.urlImage,
                                          )),
                                ))))
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Row(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                  child: Image.network(
                    widget.item.urlImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.item.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Builder(
                    builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("Buy Now"),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Payments(
                                            title: widget.item.title,
                                            urlImage: widget.item.urlImage,
                                          )),
                                ))))
              ],
            );
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Payments extends StatefulWidget {
  Payments({Key? key, required this.title, required this.urlImage})
      : super(key: key);
  String title;
  String urlImage;
  @override
  _PaymentsState createState() => _PaymentsState();
}

class _PaymentsState extends State<Payments> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RazorpayWeb(
          rzpKey: "rzp_test_DNaSxot4oJHykG", // Enter Your Razorpay Key Here
          options: RzpOptions(
            amount: 1000,
            name: '',
            description: widget.title,
            image: widget.urlImage,
            prefill: const PrefillData(
              name: "Razorpay",
              email: "rzp@gmail.com",
              contact: "9876543210",
            ),
            colorhex: "#FF0000",
          ),
          onPaymentSuccess: (String paymentId) {
            print("Payment Success");
            log(paymentId);
          },
          onPaymentError: (String error) {
            print("Payment Error");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Brother I'm looking for a solution with that we can fill dynamic data of items in razorpay options so according to product razorpay show data automatically  during the payment process
Hope would get positive response from you

Comment: Oh great man , you have amazing knowledge ! salute by heart

Comment: Brother could you resolve my this issue = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74587764/im-working-on-a-flutter-web-project-when-i-run-in-localhost-it-is-working-fine/74588650#74588650